# Can't see button inside GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, grid-layout

In Android Studio. Was following a youtube tutorial about GridLayout. Trying to use GridLayout with layout_width and height that set to wrap_content and add a button to it. But I can't see the button, or anything else I add normally.

Any idea how to fix this?

Picture: [image]

I was trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bXOr5Rk1dk&t=176s) video

He can see all of the button + text, I cant

XML Text code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code (Don't think needed):

```
package com.example.naveh.layla;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your post with the relevant code so we can better help you.

Comment: @codeMagic I just opened a new project with regular activity, added gridlayout and button. Thats it. Can't see the button. But I'll add anyway the XML Text.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: @sandip added everything

Comment: are you trying to run in android device?

Comment: use `GridLayout` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Github link :  https://github.com/buckyroberts/Source-Code-from-Tutorials/tree/master/Android_Beginners/017%20GridLayout

Use `GridLayout` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the code in my machine, It's works fine. Button is visible. Please try to change the theme of your preview section,  and also run on real device.

Comment: i tried many themes, still same problem. I can see the button when I run it on real device, but on the editor I can't. Its really annoying and when ill have a lot of buttons it will be a problem to edit like that.

Comment: Can you try to add background color of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GridLayout instead of androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout.

This helped me.